# SQLite not inserting record instantly

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I am working on an app which saves transactions in SQLite database after payment is received.
As soon as the transaction is approved, it is inserted in database and after that user is shown the approval.
I show the approval when I get the result from
sqlitedatabase.insert() method, and check that it returns row number.

```
public static boolean insert(String tableName, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, ContentValues contentValues){
        long rowId = sqLiteDatabase.insert(tableName, null, contentValues);
        return rowId != -1;
    }
```

The problem is, when the approval is shown to user, I shut down device by ejecting battery (I am testing out of battery case) and
when I reboot device, I see that **no record is inserted** in the database. That makes me think that SQLite is inserting records asynchronously after returning the row id.

I am using AsyncTask and I do inserting in the doInBackground, and I show the user approval in onPostExecute() of AsyncTask.

My question is, is there any way to make sure that the record is inserted the moment I call insert method or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Use of Worker's(WorkManager) can solve this problem for you and ensure that task is completed with given condition's.

Comment: @Anmol I don't think it has anything to do with that, my task is already finished and calls onPostExecute.

Comment: Can you try database.setTransactionSuccessful()  after insert - Marks the current transaction as successful. It may guarantee record insertion.

Comment: Is the record inserted at all? I mean, if you don't eject the battery, _when_ does the record appear ?

Comment: @marco.m  Yes, it works well when device keeps running. I don't know exactly when record appears, but when I select record from database it returns the record right after inserting (maybe it's because it gets it from cache but not physical storage), but if I remove battery and reboot, the record is not there.

Comment: Until the transaction does not end, the command may not be hard written. Try beginning the transaction, performing the insert, closing the transaction and then remove the battery.

Comment: @ACR I am working on a something like that right now, I hope it will work. Thanks for you suggestion.

Comment: @ACR Unfortunately that did not work, I called beginTransaction, insert, setTransactionSuccessful, and endTransaction methods in order but still same problem.

Comment: I even logged the insert result with Log.d("RowId", "" + rowId)
and it prints
"D/RowId: 1" but it does not actually save it into db in this case.

Comment: Is there a possibility of the database being recreated at the app restart? Just a thought. Could you have a check?

Comment: @ACR No, because I have been working on it for a long time and this is the only case transactions are not stored, normally everything works perfectly either the device is restarted or not. Also, the app is being tested by our team for months and it is not a possibility.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when the device is shutdown properly?

Comment: @ACR No it doesn't, if I turn off the device by power button after insert, there is no problem.

Comment: Also close the database after ending the transaction, since removing the battery is an abrupt condition.

Comment: Yes, I thought about closing the connection too, as I think it will flush the commits in the database. So I closed both the SQLiteDatabase object and my SQLiteOpenHelper, still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I realized what was causing the problem. 
It was SQLite's default configuration setting and synchronous setting was not FULL. According to [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous):

> **FULL (2)** When synchronous is FULL (2), the SQLite database engine will
>   use the xSync method of the VFS to ensure that all content is safely
>   written to the disk surface prior to continuing. **This ensures that an
>   operating system crash or power failure will not corrupt the database**.
>   FULL synchronous is very safe, but it is also slower. FULL is the most
>   commonly used synchronous setting when not in WAL mode.

The default configuration was not FULL and I changed it in my SQLiteOpenHelper class' onConfigure callback. And it solved the problem.

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA synchronous = 2");
}
```

Although the document states that "FULL synchronous is very safe, but it is also slower.", I haven't seen a significant performance difference despite batch inserting in some cases.